# Custom BeanParam annotations in java

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

I try to access **BeanParam**, But not possible by my side because to many events access old version jar present on classpath so I can't remove jar files from classpath. 
I tried to many way but finally,
I decided create own **BeanParam** using these links:-

[javatpoint](http://www.javatpoint.com/custom-annotation)  |
 [Annotation_Type_BeanParam_From_Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html)  |
 [Source_code_of_the_class_BeanParam](https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code-detail.php?file=./javaSource/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.java&key=a8e2e194b08fda03dc993b1917fed681)
There are code:-

**My BeanParam Interface**

```
            import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
            import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
            import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
            import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
            import java.lang.annotation.Target;

            @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
            @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
            @Documented
            public @interface myBeanParam {

            }
```

**My Model Class**

```
           import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
           public class ControllerFilterBean {

           @QueryParam("id") String row_id;
           @QueryParam("ot") String objectType;

           public String getRow_id() {
                return row_id;
            }
           public void setRow_id(String row_id) {
                this.row_id = row_id;
            }
           public String getObjectType() {
                return objectType;
            }
           public void setObjectType(String objectType) {
                this.objectType = objectType;
            }
           }
```

**my resources**

```
    public class MyResources {
        @GET
        @Path("/do/beanTest")
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Response beanTest(@myBeanParam ControllerFilterBean bean/*
        @QueryParam("id") String row_id,
        @QueryParam("ot") String objectType*/){
          System.out.println(bean.objectType);
          System.out.println(bean.row_id);
          /*System.out.println(row_id);
          System.out.println(objectType);*/
          ResponseBuilder rBuild =  Response.status(Response.Status.OK);
          return Build.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("OK").build();
      }

   }
```

then finally want access my resource class then its throw

**WARNING: No message body reader has been found for request**

I want help in my code where it's getting mistake.

Comment: You've got a typo here: `return Build.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("OK").build();` add a `r` before `Build`. Your variable is `rBuild`.

Comment: Sorry, it's writing mistake its not problem,

Comment: Why you define your own annotation?. Similar annotation does not mean that CXF will process the content. Try also `QueryParam("") ControllerFilterBean` removing `@QueryParam` inside the object. It is CXF specific, but usually works

Comment: @pedrofb I got to many problem with CXF, thats why I decided create own annotation, I want to know only one think that how to access using own annotation.

Comment: You have to use `javax.ws.rs.BeanParam`, not your custom annotation